# Pavement Engineering on Topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions regarding pavement engineering allowed on this exchange? The Q&A topics include specific pavement design software and pavement design principles in engineering.

I read through this on the [meta](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> #### Questions on Engineering Stack Exchange are usually well-received when they:
>
> - Identify a specific engineering problem
> - Require expert engineering knowledge to solve
> - Include any relevant drawings, images or references that may be necessary to understand the problem
> - Excite or challenge experienced professionals in the field

The Q&A we have had thus far meets these criteria. I can provide some example Q&A if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Design principles, yes.  Always.

"I'm looking for software", not so much.

Specific issues with specialized software, maybe - similar questions with other types of software have had limited success. Tutorial type questions fare very poorly, and are typically closed as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those types of questions are just as valid as any other civil engineering questions.

Comment: I have a couple dozen pavement engineering questions that folks have asked and I'm trying to encourage the pavement design community to use this site as a place to ask questions and get detailed responses to those questions. Many of the questions relate to a specific software (Pavement ME Design), but are also pavement engineering/design questions. I want to make sure I am not polluting the site with information that doesn't belong while still encouraging the community to use this forum. I appreciate any feedback you can provide.